# How to tweet without pressing 'tweet'

Tags: javascript, twitter

Sorry if I'm unclear or the title is unclear, my main language isn't english. I was wondering if it's possible to send out a tweet without having to 'confirm' , i have a code that, when you press a button it tweets something, but a pop up opens, so i was really looking for something that can help me but I couldn't find anything related to this topic.

```
document.querySelector('#postInfo').addEventListener('click' , function(){
    this.href = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=HEY';
});
```

The hey text is temporary, it'll come as some data from the DB.

Comment: No, all you are allowed to do is make a proposal what the user should tweet. They still have to confirm that they actually want to tweet it. If they didn't, that would mean that every website could make every visitor tweet arbitrary things, without them even noticing, which would obviously be bad.

Answer (score 0):

You may be aware of this, but you actually are able to "programatically" click objects through your code. You will have to use a querySelector to first select the button you are trying to "click" and then you will need to use the `.click()` method on the object. If you are trying to remove the object or button altogether, you will first need to get the element then use `element.parentNode.removeChild(element);` to remove the element itself.